# How to use more than one command in dos loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to call two commands in `for-loop` in dos script `.bat`. Second command is ignored. It is just showing in console and do nothing. I've been searching for more `for-loop` samples but without success.

```
:loop
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,500) do (
    REM command number 1
    adb wait-for-device shell input touchscreen swipe 1400 800 200 800 1000
    REM command number 2    
    adb wait-for-device shell input touchscreen swipe 800 1400 200 800 1000
)
goto loop
```

Comment: Are the lines `#command number ...` actually part of your batch file, or have you just added them here for illustration?

Comment: there are two commands starting with "adb", I used `#` as an comment what is what

Comment: The `#` character doesn't mean comment in batch files.

Comment: Changed to `REM`

Answer (score -3):

You could try doing this,

```
:loop
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,500) do (
goto loop
)

:commands
#command number 1
adb wait-for-device shell input touchscreen swipe 1400 800 200 800 1000
#command number 2    
adb wait-for-device shell input touchscreen swipe 800 1400 200 800 1000
goto loop
```

I am not an expert with batch files, I just am decent at typical programming, so some things may need fixed, but here is an idea.